# Ada95: Converting Integer to Character

Tags: ada

Is there a way in Ada to convert an Integer to character?

Ex:

```
TempInt := 1;
InGrid(RowIndex, ColumnIndex) := (ToCharacter(TempInt)); --This will be used to input a character value from an integer into an array of characters.
```

Is there any "ToCharacter" for Integer->Character conversion for Ada?

Answer (score 6):

You may be looking for the [`'Val`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-5.html) attribute as applied to the *discrete subtype* `Character`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923999/230513). `Character'Val` works like a function that takes an integer and returns a `Character`.

Answer (score 4):

it depends if you want to convert to the ascii code or if you just want to show the integer value as string.

Here you have an example of both cases

```
    with Ada.Text_IO;                  use Ada.Text_IO;

    procedure test is
       temp_var : Integer := 97;

    begin
       Put_Line ("Value of the integer shown as string: " & Integer'Image(temp_var));
       Put_Line ("Value of the integer shown as the ascii code: " & Character'Val(temp_var));
    end test;
```

The result is

> Value of the integer shown as string: 97
>
> Value of the integer shown as the ascii code: a

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you look over [Annex K of the LRM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95lrm/ARM_HTML/RM-K.html), as it probably covers what you want, along with a lot of other goodies you don't realise you want yet.

Among the relevant stuff in there:

Converting an integer (Foo) into a printable string representation of that integer's value:

```
Integer'image(Foo)
```

Converting an integer (Foo, between 0 and 255) into the ASCII character represented by that value:

```
Character'Val(Foo)
```

In the above example, if the value in `Foo` is 65, then the first line would return the string `"65"`, while the second would return the character `'A'`.