# Why is the type of an object a pointer to tagged typed, and not a tagged type?

Tags: oop, ada

I have 3 files: other.ads, other.adb, and test.adb.

other.ads:

```
package Other is
   type Thing is tagged record
      Stuff : String(1..4);
   end record;
   procedure Say (T : in Thing);
end Other;
```

other.adb: not shown for brevity, and not necessary for the example.

test.adb:

```
with Other;

procedure Test is
   T : Other.Thing := new Other.Thing;
begin
   T.Stuff := "test";
   T.Say;
end Test;
```

I get this error:

```
test.adb:4:23: expected type "Thing" defined at other.ads:2
test.adb:4:23: found type access to "Thing" defined at line 4
```

If I have these files instead:

other.ads:

```
package Other is
   type Thing is tagged record
      Stuff : String(1..4);
   end record;
   type Ref is access all Thing;
   procedure Say (T : in Thing);
end Other;
```

test.adb:

```
with Other;

procedure Test is
   T : Other.Ref := new Other.Thing;
begin
   T.Stuff := "test";
   T.Say;
end Test;
```

Then it compiles and runs fine.

Why can't I specify `new Other.Thing` to be of type `Other.Thing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `T` is an [*access type*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-10.html) that points to an object of type `Other.Thing` because you specified a [allocator](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-8.html) using `new`. You can also simply declare an object of type `Other.Thing` an initialize it using an [aggregate](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-3.html).

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Test is

package Other is
   type Thing is tagged record
      Stuff : String(1..4);
   end record;
end Other;

S : Other.Thing := (Stuff => "test");
T : access Other.Thing := new Other.Thing;

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(S.Stuff);
   T.Stuff := "test";
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(T.Stuff);
end Test;
```

Comment: Oh, I think I get it! To compare with C, it means I tried to declare the type as being `T` while I actually needed `&T`, right?

Comment: @Florian: I'm not sure about the C analogy; Ada offers a higher level of abstraction. For fun, elide the aggregate to see the uninitialized content of `S.Stuff`.

Answer (score 4):

If you declare a variable in Java, the way you set it up depends on whether the variable’s type is primitive. `int foo` reserves space for an integer. `Thing foo`, on the other hand, reserves space for a reference (pointer) to a `Thing`, and you use `new` to reserve space for the `Thing` itself; `Thing foo = new Thing`.

Ada isn’t like that (nor is C or C++, for that matter); when you say `Foo : Thing`, the compiler reserves space for the `Thing` right there (probably on the stack). So your first example can just read

```
   T : Other.Thing;
begin
   T.Stuff := “test”;
```

The time when you use the `new` keyword in Ada is when you need an access value for some reason, as you have forced in your second example; you’ve declared `T` as `Ref`, which is declared as `access all Thing`.

Note that in your second example, when you say

```
   T.Stuff := “test”;
```

this is actually shorthand for

```
   T.all.Stuff := “test”;
```

and some people like to put the `.all` in explicitly.

Comment: Good point about mentioning `.all` explicitly; I've (slowly) come to understand that stack v. heap is an implementation detail, but I think it's a a useful model. @Florian: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12923999/230513).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It really helps to make analogies with things I know :-). @trashgod thanks for the other link, quite helpful. I get it now! :P

Comment: Well, it's an implementation detail that you have to keep in mind to avoid leaks :) I guess that's why some people like to draw attention when pointers are involved.